# Pass variable from one php file to another

Tags: php, html

I am currently in file1.php and I want a variable from file1.php to pass to file2.php

How do I pass a variable from one php file to another?

I too want to go from file1.php to file2.php

I did following in file1.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['akknum']="jkl";
header("Location: file2.php");
```

and did following in file2.php :

```
    <?php
    echo "abc";
    echo $_SESSION['akknum'];
    ?>
```

The file2.php is opening and abc is printing but no value of "jkl" is printing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is $_SESSION a must or could you use GET and POST?

Comment: No it's not,nothing must in $_SESSION

Comment: is that case, depending on the way your visitors surf from file1.php to file2.php, you could use $_GET parameters in a link for example: `<a href="file2.php?akkum=jkl">Link to file2.php</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `session_start();` in `file2.php`.

```
session_start();
echo "abc";
echo $_SESSION['akknum'];
```

[Basic usage](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Comment: Won't super global variables reset when starting a new session?

Comment: You don't start a _new_ session. If you send the same SID, you continue to use the same session data. But if you don't start the session, `$_SESSION` will be always an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

you need to session_start the second file too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `$_SESSION` on a different file,  you'll need to call `session_start();`

**file1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['akknum']="jkl";
header("Location: file2.php");
?>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['akknum'];
//jkl
?>
```

---

Read more about [php sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)